# Haskell type signature for == and elem

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In GHCi, doing the following yield:

```
:t (==) 

(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

or

```
:t elem

elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

I am confused with the arrow going from a to a, and then a to Bool.
Is it because == or elem is a curried function?

The type signature for elem is very similar to ==, except for the additional t.  What does `t a` in `:t elem` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, operators are curried.  Let's ignore the contexts for a second (the part of the type before `=>`).

```
(==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

`(->)` associates to the right, so this means:

```
(==) :: a -> (a -> Bool)
```

That is, it's a function which, given an `a`, returns another function, which in turn takes an `a` and gives a `Bool`.  It returns the function which is only true when its argument is equal to the first `a`.

(We will set `NoMonomorphismRestriction` because otherwise it will just be extra confusing for no good reason)

```
ghci> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
ghci> let f = (==) 1
ghci> f 1
True
ghci> f 2
False
-- or just
ghci> (==) 1 2
False
```

The part before the (`=>`) puts constraints on types. `Eq a` means that `a` must be a type that supports equality.

As for the `t` in `elem`, that might be a bit advanced for you to understand fully right now. I'll give you a little bit.  Because of the context

```
(Eq a, Foldable t) => ...
```

we know that `t` has to be [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html).  Lists are foldable, and foldable doesn't mean much more than "has a `toList` method".  So you can read `elem` as:

```
elem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

and in general, when you see a foldable type, just pretend it's a list.

Comment: Thanks luqui.  Can you implement == or elem in Haskell so I can see how it would relate to the type signature? To me (a Haskell newbie), it seems that elem is a function that takes two arguments, rather than one that returns another function.

Comment: @Boon Indeed it is a two-argument function, but because of the currying you mention, that's the same as a function returning a function! Consider `f x y = x + y` - this is the same as `g x = (\y -> x + y)`, really. Likewise `elem` can't do anything useful with one argument, so instead it returns a new function that needs to be given its "second" argument.